# Overlay a frame on every webpage a visitor visits?

Tags: javascript, layout, overlay

So I want to be able to have a space that overlays content on any website with the click of a button (something that also is above everything on a web page). An example would be the Google Translate page, `http://translate.google.com/translate?u=about%3Ablank&hl=en&langpair=auto|en&tbb=1&ie=UTF-8` where the frame at the top will overlay any website that is entered in the url box.

What I want to do is have a box like this overlay every webpage, like google's translate does, but have it hide with a click of a floating image, say an arrow.
The files will be locally stored on my HDD, but I don't see this being an issue.

I don't know what languages to code this in, but I assume Javascript, however, I do not know the classes to call to do this. Any advice chaps? I'm not asking for a hand out, just a point in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to develop a browser extension.  Look here for Chrome:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

There are similar ways to do it for IE, FireFox, and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll either need to use frames or an iframe. They are very similar in how you interact with them (say to make them load a new page) although they are different in their implementation.

A great site for learning about frames is w3Schools:

- http://w3schools.com/html/html_frames.asp
- http://w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

You can use JavaScript to reference the frames via its name or its ID. Ex: document.framename.src = 'hello.php' or document.getElementById('frameId').src = 'hello.php'.

One problem with using frames is that search engines don't like them. If you are using an iframe, the search engine will search your page, but still not the iframe.

As for resizing/hiding the frame/iframe, you can do that with both frames and an iframe, although the method for accomplishing it varies depending on what you use.